# How to give access right to a user Group?

Tags: python, odoo

While providing access right to a user group it displaying a error:

> ```
> "Exception: Module loading registration_form failed: file 
>  registration_form/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
>  No matching record found for external id 'model_registration_management' 
>  in field 'Object' No matching record found for external id 
>  'registration.group_management_user' in field 'Group'
>  Missing required value for the field 'Object' (model_id) - - -
>  Missing required value for the field 'Object' ("
> ```

This is the `security.xml` file in security folder

```
<record model="ir.module.category" 
id="module_category_management">
<field name="name">Management</field>
<field name="sequence">3</field>
</record>

<record id="group_management_user" model="res.groups">
<field name="name">user</field>
<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]" />
<field name="category_id" ref="module_category_management"/>
</record>
```

Code for access rights in csv file

```
access_registration_management,registration.management,
model_registration_management,
registration.group_management_user,1,1,1,1
```

I need it to be create a user group for me but it is showing me error.

Comment: Please share the code of __manifest__.py or __openerp__.py (For older version) to check whether you added the files in which sequence.

 _Exception: Module loading registration_form failed: file_ This means that you are not defining the file correctly in __manifest__.py or __openerp__.py (For older version)

Comment: Have in mind that you have to have the files in the right order in Manifest. Because Odoo has to create the group first and then this group can be used in access files or view files.

Comment: "data":[
  "security/test_security.xml",
  "security/ir.model.access.csv",
  "data/registration_form_data.xml",
  "views/registration_student_view.xml",
  "views/registration_school_view.xml",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually occurs when there is no model model_registration_management in your module. Please make sure that you define model correctly in your module and in xml file.
there is similar question you can refer [this link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/why-does-module-loading-fail-4940)